# What do you call the sounds that play when players place/destroy blocks?

Tags: sound, terminology

I'm working on a game and trying to find sounds for it. I'm not sure what terminology to use when searching to find the *kinds* of sounds I need.

Specifically I'm looking for sounds that make sense for when a player places or destroys a block in my game. What are these sort of incidental environment background effects called in general, so I can better refine my searches?

Answer (score 1):

I think asking for assets/asset sites is off-topic, but there's a glimmer of an on-topic question here about asset *terminology*. ("I don't know, what I can Google, or how these sounds are called.")

If I interpret your question as **"What are the terms used for sound effects like placing blocks in games?"**...

[Then I think the word you're looking for may be "foley."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foley_(filmmaking)) This is used to refer to all the incidental sounds of action & movement in the game world, like footsteps or rustling & jangling of clothing/armor, or the impact sounds when an object strikes/lands against another surface.

A good foley kit will usually have a bunch of combinations like "impact, wood, soft" "impact, wood, heavy" "scrape, metal, medium" or maybe even destruction sounds like "crumbling stone"

Of course, that assumes you're looking for a sound based in physical intuition about familiar materials. Since it's a game, we can control the world however we like, and decree that "placing a block" sounds like that sound old CRT televisions made when you turned them off, and "destroying a block" sounds like opera singing. If you're going super-imaginative with your sounds though, there's probably no one term that would encompass everything you're looking for, so you'd need to specify a lot more precisely what you want these things to sound like in your game world.

Comment: This is a good answer, I think it's worth making the question fit it.

Comment: Thanks @Josh! I'm trying to take the advice to look for constructive questions within iffy posts, rather than just closing, but I wasn't sure whether making such an edit would "clearly conflict with the author's intent" even if the intent was off-topic...

Comment: Technically it does, but I think the value proposition is worthwhile for the site overall to mostly-ignore that rule if the question's already closed. A radically changed, but open, question is generally better for everybody than a closed one (unless there are multiple conflicting answers that can't be rectified in the edit or something).